# JavaScript alert works normally Firefox, but not in Chrome and Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have simple jquery code and "show alert" button on my page

when i click "show alert" button; all the design of the page is distorted.
it works normally Firefox, but not in Chrome and Explorer.

plaese refer link for problem : http://bit.ly/1vnHPU2

```
$(function() {

      $("#buttonAlert").click( function()
           {
             alert('button clicked');
           }
      );
});
```

---

edit:

**i Cleared all click  function of script bloks on page. But problem is not sloved.**

Thank You!

Comment: It seems to work for me in all browsers.

Comment: it should be `$("#buttonAlert").click( function()` right???

Comment: what is your chrome and ie version ?

Comment: Yes it's named buttonAlert on working page

Comment: Chrome version is :37.0.2062.124 and Explorer is v11

Comment: Is it possible that your `click` listener works fine but something is overwriting `alert` in Chrome and IE?

Comment: There are no alert or click functions on page now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i sloved to problem when adding tag button type

```
   <button  class="btn btn-primary btn-block"  id="buttonAlert" name="buttonAlert"  >  Show Alert  </button>
```

to

```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"  id="buttonAlert" name="buttonAlert"  >  Show Alert  </button>
```

Thanks all of friends to interested this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

      $("#buttonAlert").on("click", function()
           {
             alert('button clicked');
           }
      );
});
```

Try that, sometimes i have issues with just ".click()"

Comment: i try but repeats same problem

Comment: The button is triggering something else. See if anything else is calling #buttonAlert

Comment: `on("click"...)` and `click(...)` are going to result in the same thing.

Comment: Yes, however in a few situations one works and one doesn't. Not sure where the issue is but i have had to try both to get one of them to work.

Comment: no other found anything named buttonAlert in this web project

Comment: @NicholasYoung is correct. There are issues with trying to use multiple click event handlers on 1 element. To get them both working, you need to add you alert code to where the first instance of the event handler is.

Comment: @Progy If nothing else, you can ALWAYS take the lazy way out, and add a return false in there. No where near the right solution... But it solves your problem. ;)

Comment: i Cleared all click of function script bloks on page. But problem is not sloved.

Comment: Its still bound to something, your page is changing on every click.